# Google Play Games Services - Realtime Multiplayer - STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer

I am trying to implement a real-time multiplayer in my *Android* game using
the *Google Play Games Services* but I am facing an issue when the `onRoomCreated` method, that I overrided, is called.

```
  @Override
  public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
      stopKeepingScreenOn();
      showGameError();
      return;
    }
    roomId = room.getRoomId();
    showWaitingRoom(room);
  }
```

The status code is always different of `GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK` and actually equal to 2 (+ the `room` parameter is null), which means according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes.html#STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) :

> The GoogleApiClient is in an inconsistent state and must reconnect to
>   the service to resolve the issue. Further calls to the service using
>   the current connection are unlikely to succeed.

But there is no change if I call `getApiClient().reconnect()`. So I would really appreciate any help. For information, `getApiClient()` comes from the `GameHelper` class that I extend and which is provided in the library from the [Android samples page](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples).

Answer (score 1):

onRoomConnected is called when the client attempts to create a real-time room. The real-time room can be created by calling the createRoom(RoomConfig) operation which create a real-time room for the current game. The lifetime of the current game's connection to the room is bound to this GamesClient's lifecycle. When the client disconnects, the player will leave the room and any peer-to-peer connections for this player will be torn down.

You can visit this [page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient#createRoom(com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomConfig)) for more information.

You can also check this [document](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_1_sign_in_to_the_dev_console) on how to use the Google Play Developer Console to set up Google Play games services if you forgot something.

Comment: It appeared that I solved my problem recently. The issue was due to the fact that I was trying to use the _Google Play Games Services_ without generating a signed APK with the same certificate I used to add a linked app to my game service in the _Google Play Developer Console_.

Comment: David Baron is right. I changed my Laptop where i programmed my first version of my app. So i had to add a new OAuth 2.0 client IDs that had my new SHA1 key (from my new Laptop).