# Android Google Play TurnBasedMatch unable to create match from second machine

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am working on a version-controlled Google TurnBasedMatch Android application on two separate machines.

What works:

- Creating matches and taking turns between Gmail 1 and Gmail 2 from devices  running the debug app from Machine 1
- Viewing in-progress matches between Gmail 1 and Gmail 2 from devices running the debug app from Machine 2

What does **not** work:

- Creating matches and taking turns between Gmail 1 and Gmail 2 from devices  running the debug app from Machine 2. Reading match data from an already existing game works fine, but any attempt to create a new match or alter an existing match results in GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED

I have generated an OAuth 2.0 client ID for each of the two machines and added them to the Google Developer Console. That seemed to be the solution to the similar issue [on this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904481/google-play-games-services-realtime-multiplayer-status-client-reconnect-requ). Before this was added, I wasn't even able to login to Play Services, so I am unsure if this is related to the current issue.

Looking for ideas on credential/access-based differences that could exist between the two machines.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out - the key was to create a "Linked app" in the Google Play Console for each of the OAuth 2.0 Clients generated in the Google Developer Console. I only had an app linked to Machine 1 previously.