# Android RealTimeMultiplayer onRoomCreated getting status 2 : STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to setup realtime multiplayer in my Android Game. However, when I call `Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(googleApiClient, roomConfig);` after selecting the players.

However every time `onRoomCreated` is called with status `STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED` and room `null`:

```
@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
  if (statusCode == STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
    // This gets called repeatedly
    reconnectGoogleLogin();
    return;
  } else if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
    disableAlwaysOnScreen();
    return;
  }

  Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(
    googleApiClient, room, MIN_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS);
  startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}
```

I have tried a number of things before asking this:

1. Yes I checked my Google Play Developer Console, the Realtime Multiplayer Settings is ON in the Linked Apps
2. The APK installed is with a valid sign key, I have the debug key-store as valid.
3. Looked through the documentation, but I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

Would love some help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904481/google-play-games-services-realtime-multiplayer-status-client-reconnect-requ

Comment: I had looked at that but that does not solve it. (Point 2 in the things I did is basically from there) :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what this problem was?

Comment: Make sure you didn't add the debug keystore manually (create another linked app). https://stackoverflow.com/a/56463302/5434860